# passing Execute Sql Task Result set object to For Each Loop container

Tags: ssis

i have written a oracle query in Script Task and assigned it to string variable. This is my query

```
string oracle_query = "SELECT bank_ID, Branch_ID, Trans_NUM, Trans_DT, convert(Varchar(25),quantity) AS quantity  FROM OPENQUERY(orcale_server_name,  'SELECT * "
                + "FROM oracletable" +
                 " where bank_ID =''" + Dts.Variables["User::bank_ID"].Value.ToString() + "'' AND Trans_DT = ''" + Dts.Variables["User::Trans_DT"].Value.ToString() + "'' AND quantity = " + Dts.Variables["User::quantity"].Value.ToString() + " AND Branch_ID = ''" + Dts.Variables["User::Branch_ID"].Value.ToString() + "'' ')";
```

the result of this query has been assigned to string variabl which i have declared in my package

```
Dts.Variables["oraclequery"].Value = oracle_query; .
```

output of this query is

```
bank_ID  Branch_ID  Trans_Num  Trans_DT   Quantity  
12         13       12AS566    2012-01-01  4000
```

Based on Trans_Num column i need to update one more table.

Instead of script task i can use oledb TranFormation, but while passing Running parameters in Oledb Source, no data is coming.

So the result of script task i have assigned to OracleQuery varibale and passed as source variable in Execute Sql Task and resultset as **Full Result Set** .

This Execute SQl Task resultset i have passed to for each loop container and inside varibale index i have assigned OracleQuery Varibale.

but still no data is populating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.First you need to create variables for the column being retrieved from your oracle query

2.Then the variable `oraclequery` should be of type System.Object

3.In the `resultSet` tab of Execute SQL task assign the result to the variable `oraclequery`

```
ResultName    VariableName 
 0            oraclequery
```

4.Then in the ForEach Loop use `ADO Enumerator` and select `ADO Object SourceVariable` to oraclequery and click the radio button `Rows in the First Table`

In the variable mapping of for each loop, map the columns in the same order as it is being retrieved from the query .

```
 Variable     Index 
  BankId       0
  Branch_ID    1 
 ....          ..
```

Now you can access these variable inside inside a `DFT` placed in the Foreach loop and then use `OLEDB component` to update another table based on the `Trans_Num`

For more details refer this [article](http://thesearchendshere.wordpress.com/category/exploring-ado-enumerator-in-execute-sql-task/) and [this](http://www.sqlis.com/post/The-Execute-SQL-Task.aspx)

Comment: what should i use in Execute SQl task as source . i canot write direct oracle query there. i think it wont supports

Comment: Having connectionType as OLEDB it does support oracle query

Comment: When you write that query in execute sql task ,you need to specify the parameters for the variable in your where clause http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2006/11/17/amazing-ssis-parameters-in-execute-sql-task.aspx

Comment: i mapped, variables to for each loop container, to check whether am getting the values or not, i have placed script task inside foreach loop and in readonly varibales i have one of the 4 variables user::TransNum and inside script task i have written string trans = dts.variables["Trans_Num"].value.tostring(). But after for each loop it is not going inside Script task

Comment: r u getting values from the oracle query ? try placing a script task after execute sql task and see whether the query returns value or not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14624/discussion-between-user1348424-and-praveen)